# If four number cells match, return value from 5th cell

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a formula function that will return the value of E in column F if A matches with B, and C matches with D.

Excel worksheet -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmcry.png

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,C2=D2),E2,"")
```